# Php curl headers default content type not changing

Tags: php, curl

In curl default content type not changing 'application/json' in output.

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/xml';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/xml';
   $url = url('someurl here');
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $response=curl_exec($ch);
   $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
   curl_close($ch);
```

**Output:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Request-Time: 295
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2017 07:41:58 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
```

am i done any mistake in that above code? I need output in xml format only.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake. Content-type header that you setted is a request header. It defines type of content that you're sending to a server. Which make no sense in GET requests type.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
...
```

Is a response headers. Content type here shows format of the server response.

Maybe you didn't pass some parameter that tells server to return xml data instead of json.